# Vuejs 2 - Passing data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new in `Vuejs` so I am sure is my code. I have this simple `app.vue` file and I want to get the data from `JSON` and then setup my menu based on the data. I do a simple test:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data:function(){
    return{
      menu:[]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    GetMenu:function(s){
      $.get({
    url: 'static/json/menu.json',
    success:function(res) {
      s = res.menu;
      console.log(s[0].artist);//<-- have result
    }
    })
    }
  },
  created:function(){
    this.GetMenu(this.menu);
    console.log(this.menu);//<-- have [__ob__:Observer]
  }
}
```

If I run the code above I will get the result from `console.log(this.menu)` first, which is `[__ob__:Observer]`, then only result from `console.log(s[0].artist)`, which is what I want. I did try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
console.log(this.menu);//<-- undefined
},2000);
```

Then I get `undefined`. 
How can I resolve this?

**Update01**

I tried:

```
export default {
      name: 'app',
      data:function(){
        return{
          menu:[]
        }
      },
      methods:{
        GetMenu:function(){
          $.get({
        url: 'static/json/menu.json',
        success:function(res) {
        console.log(res);//<-- result
          return res.menu;
        }
        })
        }
      },
      mounted:function(){
        this.menu = this.GetMenu();
        console.log(this.menu);//<-- undefined
      }
    }
```

Basically, I change the `GetMenu()` to `return res.menu` then do `this.menu = this.GetMenu();`. I am still getting `undefined`.

Comment: "this.menu" within the timeout callback does not have the correct context. "this" at that point is likely the global Window. Try sending this as the setTimeout parameter: $.proxy(function() { console.log(this.menu); }, this) and see what gets logged.

Comment: I tried `$.proxy` as you suggest but nothing happen.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help... Since I don't know anything about Vuejs, I will defer to others that know better. Bert Evans answer looks promising!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your `this` is pointing to the wrong thing. Additionally, there is no need to pass `this.menu`.

```
{
  name: 'app',
  data:function(){
    return{
      menu:[]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    GetMenu:function(){
      $.get({
        url: 'static/json/menu.json',
        success:function(res) {
          this.menu = res.menu;
        }.bind(this)
      })
    }
  },
  created:function(){
    this.GetMenu();
  }
}
```

See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I use your way and it works. Thanks for the reference about `this`. Anyway, the `console.log()` still did not give me the correct result but the data did show up(I put it straight into html).